# Material-UI DataGrid dynamic row height based on text content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using DataGrid, I cannot figure out how to make row heights variable, so that the row's height is dynamically based on the length of the text content in the cell.

I was thinking I would need to add `renderCell` on the column with the longer text, and use the `<Typography>` component, but I don't know what params to use to style it this way.

There is a lot of documentation on how to handle truncation, ellipsis, etc, but I cannot seem to figure out what I need to apply for variable row heights based on content.

Comment: The same problem, still looking...

Answer (score 29):

As of Data Grid version [5.12.0](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/releases/tag/v5.12.0) there is support for dynamic row height.

To use it:

```
<DataGrid getRowHeight={() => 'auto'} />
```

See documentation [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/rows/#dynamic-row-height) for more details.

Comment: Still working in version 18.1...

Answer (score 20):

```
const StyledDataGrid = withStyles({
    root: {
        '& .MuiDataGrid-renderingZone': {
            maxHeight: 'none !important',
        },
        '& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
            lineHeight: 'unset !important',
            maxHeight: 'none !important',
            whiteSpace: 'normal',
        },
        '& .MuiDataGrid-row': {
            maxHeight: 'none !important',
        },
    },
})(DataGrid);
```

See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-row-height-j4xvq) demo for an example.

Comment: the last row of the table gets cut with this solution. You can try adding 2 more rows to the demo link provided and see it in action.

Comment: @krishna Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: No, I ended up using popover component for elements as explained here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/417

Comment: Its a bit of a flawed design in my opinion.  Everything should be responsive these days.  The height of the grid should of course depend upon the height of all the lines in the grid, if text is allowed to wrap then that should add to the grids hieght.  I was very surprised to see that you have to specify a height on the grid, number of rows should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the other answers, it COULD be possible, if you disable the virtualization. But beware, you are disabling performance optimizations.

```js
export const StyledDataGrid = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiDataGrid-renderingZone': {
      maxHeight: 'none !important'
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
      lineHeight: 'unset !important',
      maxHeight: 'none !important',
      whiteSpace: 'normal',
      wordWrap: 'break-word'
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-row': {
      maxHeight: 'none !important'
    }
  },
  virtualScrollerContent: {
    height: '100% !important',
    overflow: 'scroll'
  }
})(DataGrid);
```

Then disable the virtualization:

```js
<StyledDataGrid disableVirtualization />
```

Answer (score 3):

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-height/

just add getRowHeight={() => 'auto'} like so:

```
<DataGrid getRowHeight={() => 'auto'} />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/417) thread it's not possible.

> @ronnyroeller thanks for the feature request. It's definitely something we were expecting. We are happy to see it surface :). For the virtualization to work, the grid needs to know the size of all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do -

Import this at the top of your theme -

```
import type {} from '@mui/x-data-grid/themeAugmentation';
```

in the `components` section of your theme paste this

```
MuiDataGrid: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      '& .MuiDataGrid-main > div:nth-child(2)': {
        height: 'fit-content !important',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with 7th version of `@mui/x-data-grid`:

```
<DataGrid
  rows={lines}
  columns={columns}
  disableRowSelectionOnClick
  getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
  sx={{
    [`& .MuiDataGrid-cell`]: {
      paddingTop: 1.5,
      paddingBottom: 1.5,
      lineHeight: 'unset !important',
      maxHeight: 'none !important',
      whiteSpace: 'normal',
    },
    [`& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader`]: {
      maxHeight: 'none !important',
      height: 'auto !important',
      whiteSpace: 'inherit !important',
      overflow: 'inherit !important',
      lineHeight: '24px !important'
    },
    [`& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle`]: {
      whiteSpace: 'normal !important',
    },
  }}
/>
```